# Regex to add (-) in between string

Tags: regex

I want to display string like this format :

```
784-2023-1234567-4
```

My regex: `/^((784)([0-9]{12}))$/;​`

Comment: A regex doesn't add things. If you want to add hyphens, you need a programming language.

Comment: Please specify which language are you using and what are your attempts for solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
784[\d-]{15}
```

or

```
784-\d*-\d*-\d*
```

or

```
784-\d{4}-\d{7}-\d
```

Your question is very vague and not informative, be careful in advance.